# Faker in Django: Instance of 'Generator' has no 'name' memberpylint(no-member)

Tags: python, django, faker

I am new to Python.
How do I resolve the following problem in Django and faker?

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
from first_app.models import Customer
from faker import Faker
fakegen=Faker()

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range (N):
        fake_name=fakegen.name()
        fake_street=fakegen.street_name()
        fake_suburb=fakegen.city()
        fake_city=fakegen.city()
        fake_phone=fakegen.phone_number()
        fake_email=fakegen.mail()
        fake_website=fakegen.url
        fake_bus=fakegen.company

        customer=Customer.objects.get_or_create(name=fake_name,street=fake_street,suburb=fake_suburb,city=fake_city,phone=fake_phone,email=fake_email,website=fake_website,bus_type=fake_bus)[0]


if __name__=='__maine__':
    print('populating script')
    populate(20)
    print('population complete')
```

I am getting this error:

> Instance of 'Generator' has no 'name' memberpylint(no-member)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

pylint error isn't a concerning error.... You can use the following comment in your script to avoid the error notification :

## #pylint: disable=no-member

Here after disable you need to provide the rule name. You can provide multiple rule names by separating them with comma in a single line.